# How can i send a entire array inside a function and shift it and bring it back to the main code?

Tags: arrays, c, arduino

I'm trying to send a set of ultrasonic sensor data which is stored in an array, to a function to perform a right shift and replace the first element with 99 and bring it back to the main code. But unfortunately I can't bring the array back to the main code and print it. please help me to solve this.

*BTW what I'm trying to do is to update the array with the latest value from the sensor and shift the rest to left and remive the last element from the array every time the loop runs. if there a better way to do this please mention it as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arrayShift(double *data,int count);

/*Ultrasonic Sensor data*/

const int trigP = 2;  //D4 Or GPIO-2 of nodemcu
const int echoP = 0;  //D3 Or GPIO-0 of nodemcu

long duration;
int distance;
int level;
int maxL=430;

/*************************************************/
void setup()
{
    /*********************************************/

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    /*Ultrasonic Sensor data*/

    pinMode(trigP, OUTPUT);  // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(echoP, INPUT);   // Sets the echoPin as an Input
    /*********************************************/
}

void loop()
{
    /*Ultrasonic Sensor data*/

    digitalWrite(trigP, LOW);   // Makes trigPin low
    delayMicroseconds(2);       // 2 micro second delay 

    digitalWrite(trigP, HIGH);  // tigPin high
    delayMicroseconds(10);      // trigPin high for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigP, LOW);   // trigPin low

    double data[] = {1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400};
    duration = pulseIn(echoP, HIGH);   //Read echo pin, time in microseconds
    distance= duration*0.034/2;        //Calculating actual/real distance
    double temp;
    int address;
    level = maxL - distance;            //Calculating waret level

    Serial.print("Distance = ");        //Output distance on arduino serial monitor 
    Serial.println(distance);
    Serial.print("Duration = ");        //Output distance on arduino serial monitor 
    Serial.println(duration);


    /****************************************************/
    /* Shifting and adding most recent data*/

    Serial.println("before shift");
    for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) {
        Serial.print(data[i]);
        Serial.println("");

        address=arrayShift(data,20);

        Serial.println("after shift");
        for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) {
            Serial.print(data[i]);
            Serial.print("");     

            Serial.println(address);
            Serial.println("check");

            delay(3000);                        //Pause for 3 seconds and start measuring distance again

            /*********************************************/  
        }
    }


    /************** Functions ***************************/

    int arrayShift(double *data,int count)
    {
        double temp = *data; 
        double newData[20];

        for(int x=0; x<count; x++) {
            newData[x]=*data;
            data++;
        }

        Serial.println("new data");
        for (int i = 0; i <20; i++) {
            Serial.print(newData[i]);
            Serial.print("");
        }

        for (int i = 19; i >0; i--) {
            newData[i] = data[i-1];
        }

    }

    newData[0] = 99;
    return *newData;
}
```

Comment: Edit your post and fix the indention & code formatting. It's all over the place.

Comment: Note: Arduino IDE projects are actually C++ in disguise, not C.

Comment: @Ruks `newData` is a local array, so `return newData;` returns a pointer that will be invalid.

Comment: Your brackets are messed up. You have the `arrayShift` function inside the `loop` function. Fix that first, then we can address the other issues.

Comment: You shouldn't be using double on AVR... because it's an AVR, not a PC.

Comment: You should simplify your program to test the function `arrayShift` individually with a simple `main` function that uses hard-coded data to call `arrayShift`. If you don't have a compiler and debugger for your PC you could use e.g. https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: If there is a lot of shifting going on, consider using a ring buffer.

Answer (score 1):

`arrayShift` can just modify the array in place:

```
void arrayShift(double *data, unsigned int count, double newval)
{
    while (count >= 2)
    {
        data[count - 1] = data[count - 2];
        count--;
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        data[0] == newval;
    }
}
```

Example call:

```
    arrayShift(data, 20, 99.0);
```

Comment: ill ty this as well.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the return type of your function.
`int arrayShift(double *data,int count)`  to
`double* arrayShift(double* data,int count)`
and when you return you need to return the pointer to the data so instead of`return *newData;`
use `return newData;`
Another problem is that when you copy the data to the newData array

```
for(int x=0; x<count; x++){
 newData[x]=*data;
 data++;
}
```

You increment the pointer and then use that pointer. Which mean your accessing memory that you don't have access to. Here:

```
    for (int i = 19; i >0; i--){
        newData[i] = data[i-1];
    }
```

to fix this you need to use the temp variable as a pointer

```
double *temp=data;
for(int x=0; x<count; x++){
 newData[x]=*temp;
 temp++;
}
```

But now that we return the newData array we need to allocate the memory with `malloc` because if we don't the memory is freed as soon as the function finishes.
so this `double newData[20]` needs to become this `double *newData=(double*)malloc(20*sizeof(double));`
or better this `double *newData=(double*)malloc(count*sizeof(double));`
But now we have introduced a memory leak which needs to be handled in the loop function.

Full corrected function:

```
double* arrayShift(double *data,int count) {
  

 double *temp = data; 
 double *newData=(double*)malloc(count*sizeof(double));
 
 for(int x=0; x<count; x++){ //Copy main data to newData array

    newData[x]=*temp;
    temp++;
 
 }
 
    Serial.println("new data");
    for (int i = 0; i <20; i++){
       Serial.print(newData[i]);
       Serial.print("");
    }
 
    for (int i = 19; i >0; i--){
      newData[i] = data[i-1];
    }

  
    newData[0] = 99;
    return newData;
}
```

But another problem is that in you main code you use the same data array and not the the array that is returned.

```
address=arrayShift(data,20);

  Serial.println("after shift");
    for (int i = 0; i <20; i++){

       Serial.print(data[i]);// old data
       Serial.print("");
}
```

To fix this you need to first change the type of the address variable from `int address;` to `double* address=NULL;`

```
if(address!=NULL){
 free(address); //handle the memory leak
}
address=arrayShift(data,20);

  Serial.println("after shift");
    for (int i = 0; i <20; i++){

       Serial.print(address[i]);// new data
       Serial.print("");
}
```

But now you need to copy the data from the address array to the data array so you don't lose the data after the `free(address)`. So in this case the function below make much more sense.

So if you want the same array to be changed you just need to use this:

```
void arrayShift(double *data,int count) {
        
    for (int i = 19; i >0; i--){
        data[i] = data[i-1];
    }
    data[0] = 99;
}
```

The above function shifts right your main data array without a need to return it and you can use the data array just like this in you main code.
In the loop function:

```
arrayShift(data,20);
Serial.println("after shift");
for (int i = 0; i <20; i++){
 Serial.print(data[i]);
 Serial.print(""); 
}
```

I also think you had one extra bracket in your arrayshift function.

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, I'll try this and get back asap. thank you again.

Comment: @IsuruB No problem, glad to help.